# Repeating an object created with graphics on python 3

Tags: python

I have created 4 small circles using python graphics. I want to repeat this certain action to go 5 times to the right. This is only a part of the code that's why i have a main function.

```
from graphics import *

def main ():
    win = GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)
    patchWork(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def patchWork(win):
    x = 105
    y = 5
    startpoint = Point(x, y)
    circle = Circle(startpoint, 5)
    circle2 = Circle(Point(115,5),5)
    circle3 = Circle(Point(105, 15), 5)
    circle4 = Circle(Point(115, 15), 5)
    circle.draw (win)
    circle2.draw (win)
    circle3.draw (win)
    circle4.draw (win)
```

Comment: just make x,y a parameter and then have a loop in the main?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to draw 5 cycles. So I guess we just use a loop.

```
from graphics import *
def main ():
    win = GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)
    x = 105
    y = 5
    for i in range(5): #do 5 times
        patchWork(win, x, y)
        x = x + 5 #you may change this if need be
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def patchWork(win, x, y):
    circle = Circle(Point(x, y), 5) #no need to draw multiple circles here, just call patchWork a few times.
    circle.draw (win)
```

But maybe you also want to go into the y-axis? No problem! The loop will help you again:

```
from graphics import *
def main ():
    win = GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)
    x = 105
    y = 5
    for j in range(5): #do 5 times in y-axis
        for i in range(5): #do 5 times in the x-axis
            patchWork(win, x, y)
            x = x + 5 #you may change this if need be
        y = y + 5 #you may change this if need be
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def patchWork(win, x, y):
    circle = Circle(Point(x, y), 5) #no need to draw multiple circles here, just call patchWork a few times.
    circle.draw (win)
```

This will draw 5*5 so 20 cycles. No need for repeated code.

One important lesson to take home: Don't repeat code if possible. If you are starting to write down the name of a function many times then there is often a better and easier solution waiting for you.

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted thank you very much. The only thing is that only the circles on the x axes appear whereas the circles on the y axe doesn't seem to appear at all. All i get is 5 circles going horizontally and not going vertically. If you have a solution it would be much appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated my code, it had bug. If it work please mark as answered so that people can see that we finished.